# Validating in-app purchase via jquery -- 21002 errors

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to validate a purchase using jquery, and no matter what I try, I get a "receipt data malformed" error. I've got a valid receipt which looks like this:

```
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
```

and I'm sending it off to the server using Jquery:

```
$.post(
    "https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt", 
    {
        "receipt-data": "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"
    }, 
    function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
)
```

and I keep getting back this "malformed request" error message. The code's valid base64, it decompresses to:

```
{
"signature" = "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";
"purchase-info" = "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";
"environment" = "Sandbox";
"pod" = "100";
"signing-status" = "0";
}
```

What could be causing this? The base64's valid, the "receipt-data": [receipt] seems to be correct... Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For posterity,

When you use jQuery's post method, the string it forms from the second argument JavaScript object is not a JSON literal. Instead, it probably is doing something like this:

```
{
   "receipt-data" : "< receipt data here >"
}
```

becomes

```
"receipt-data=< receipt data here >"
```

almost like a GET request.

However, when you use JSON.stringify(), you get a JSON literal from a JavaScript object.

In this respect, Apple's validation server is a bit non-standard, since it expects POST data to be formatted as JSON instead of the older GET-style string.

Comment: I **cannot** upvote this enough. Ensure you are calling JSON.stringify() on the data before sending it.

Answer (score 2):

I have just tried to hit your request url using chrome extension app "Postman" and got successfully this :

```
{
"receipt":
{"original_purchase_date_pst":"2013-07-10 12:33:51 America/Los_Angeles", "purchase_date_ms":"1373563377932", "unique_identifier":"0000b02187b8", "original_transaction_id":"1000000080013872", "bvrs":"1.03", "transaction_id":"1000000080161855", "quantity":"1", "unique_vendor_identifier":"C8BB0C6C-5397-4CE6-9FC6-1B1076DCD811", "item_id":"668501516", "product_id":"PP_001", "purchase_date":"2013-07-11 17:22:57 Etc/GMT", "original_purchase_date":"2013-07-10 19:33:51 Etc/GMT", "purchase_date_pst":"2013-07-11 10:22:57 America/Los_Angeles", "bid":"nz.co.prophotographer.app", "original_purchase_date_ms":"1373484831000"
},
"status":0}
```

and i guess there is no such error "malformed request". that means there should be a error in code for making request to server.

Comment: Hmm, interesting... I wonder if there's something about jquery's post request that isn't what apple's looking for? Surely the jquery code posted above generates the same kind of request... argh!

Answer (score 0):

Doing it this way works correctly, for some reason:

```
$.post(
    "https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt", 
    JSON.stringify({ "receipt-data": "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"}), 
    function(result) {
        console.log(result)
    }
);
```

I have no idea why you have to pass the data as a string; surely it should be the same? Every other jquery post I've ever made was by passing the data as a json object... :/ Got the working example code from http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.phonegap/38338